# recursive to standard convertion

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

I have been trying to find an equation for a sequence, and got interested on how to convert any recursive sequence ex: $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},\space F_0=1,\space F_1=1$ into a standard equation
ex: $F_n=\frac 1{\sqrt 5}(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2)^{n+1}-\frac 1{\sqrt 5}(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2)^{n+1}$ I decided to search around but only got beginners algebra stuff, in fact the only helpful thing I found was a [video on how to do it with the Fibonacci sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5tBvxDM9V4) which doesn't help me with the equation I have. if anyone could give me a link to something helpful, that would be appreciated, and if you want to tackle the equation, here you go:
$f_n=\begin{cases}
\text{if n is even} & f_{\big(\frac n2\big)}+f_{\big(\frac n2-1\big)}\\
\text{if n is odd} & f_{\big(\frac{n-1}2+1\big)} \\
\end{cases}\space f_0=1,\space f_1=1$
or
$$f_n=\frac{(-1)^n+1}2\bigg(f_{\big(\frac n2\big)}+f_{\big(\frac n2-1\big)}\bigg)-\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}2\bigg(f_{\big(\frac{n-1}2+1\big)}\bigg),\space f_0=1,\space f_1=1$$
if you get an answer can you show how you got it and what it is?

Comment: I'm confused... this is the Fibonacci sequence, right? It's shifted a little (the $0$th and $1$st terms are $1$ instead of the $1$st and $2$nd terms), but it generates the same numbers. Can't you just adapt the formula for the $n$th Fibonacci number?

Comment: @TheoBendit are you talking about the examples I gave?

Comment: Right, that's what I missed: they are examples, not what you're interested in. There are plenty of resources on the web for how to solve homogeneous second order linear recurrence relations, e.g. https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf

Comment: Mind you, that won't help your given recurrence relation. I don't think you'll find any general methods to tackle such a monster.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you, is that what there called. no wonder I couldn't find anything about them. and even though it might not help I'll see anyway

Comment: I think it's good for you to read page 120 of "[Topics in Algebra and Analysis: Preparing for the Mathematical Olympiad](https://books.google.com/books?id=C2GYBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&dq=solving%20recursive%20equation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4qqHZw9HiAhWiTd8KHfeODfUQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=solving%20recursive%20equation&f=false)". Actually there are many methods to solve recursive equation and I am not sure which of them is good for your sequence but this introduction familiarize you with these methods.

Comment: Well, the problem with your recurrence relation is that there's no bounded order here. We say the recurrence relation is of order $k$ if $f_n$ depends only on $f_{n-1}, f_{n - 2}, \ldots, f_{n - k}$. However, in this case, $f_{2n}$ depends on $f_n$ and $f_{n + 1}$, which means it is not of finite order.

Comment: thank you, I will see if this will help

Comment: page 120 seems to be  blocked to me

Comment: Are you aware that $\sin(\pi(n+\frac 1 2)) = (-1)^n$, so that the “monster factors” are either one or zero? Also – unless I made an error – you'll get for $n=2$ that $f_2 = f_1 + f_2 = 1 + f_2 $, which has no solution.

Comment: @MartinR yes, i did notice the first part but I do not agree with the second and $(-1)^n$ is eather $1$ or $-1$ not $1$ or $0$

Comment: @spydragon: But your factors are $((-1)^n+1)/2$ and $((-1)^{n+1}+1)/2$ that is either one or zero. What do *you* get for $f_2$?

Comment: @MartinR $f_0+f_1=1+1=2$, ok now I agree with the $0$ and $1$

Comment: @spydragon: Do you see now that $n=2$ gives $f_2 = 1 + f_2$ and that there is no solution?

Comment: @MartinR ok now I see, but that's only because of a small error on my part the $f_{\frac {n}{2}+1}$ should be $f_{\frac {n}{2}-1}$ I will fix that now.

Comment: Your sequence is now this: http://oeis.org/A002487.

Comment: @MartinR ya I know the only reason I didn't say is because I want to learn this, and that I would probably get answers related to the formulas given for that sequence. That wouldn't help me since I don't understand them.

Answer (score 0):

We can make the following.

We'll choose values $k$ and $m$, for which our sequence it's
$$F_n+kF_{n-1}=m\left(F_{n-1}+kF_{n-2}\right)$$ or
$$F_n=(m-k)F_{n-1}+mkF_{n-2}.$$
Thus, $$m-k=1$$ and $$mk=1,$$ which after solving of this system gives
$$k=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$$ and $$m=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}.$$
Id est, $$F_n+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}F_{n-1}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\left(F_{n-1}+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}F_{n-2}\right).$$
We see that $a_n=F_n+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}F_{n-1}$ is a geometric progression, $a_1=1$ and we obtain:
$$F_n+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}F_{n-1}=a_n=a_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{n-1}.$$

Now, use the telescopic sum.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Can the down-voter explain your step?

Comment: (I am not the one who down voted) I assume its because that your solution is for the Fibonacci sequence and not for what I'm looking for

Comment: @spydragon I explained how you can get this formula. It's exactly, that you are looking for. By the way, this method works for any recurrence in the type $a_{n+2}=pa_{n+1}+qa_n$ or $a_{n+k}=p_1a_{n+k-1}+...+p_ka_n.$

Comment: maybe so but my equation isn't that it isn't just plain addition or subtraction it has to do with multiplication as well which can't be written the way that you have put it (I think) and even if it can, you would probably have to explain it more in depth (read my bio to know why).

Comment: @spydragon I am ready to explain more. You need to say only, that you want this. Which step in my solution is not clear?

Comment: the only thing unclear is that your are using $F_n$ which usually stands for the Fibonacci sequence, so is your answer talking about the Fibonacci sequence or mine?

Comment: @spydragon We say about your sequence, of course. But this method is valid for all recurrence like this.

Comment: the only problem with that is that (as I stated) I want to learn how to do it. now your answer might be good enough for other people to understand but I'm not even out of high school yet, I purposefully get in things over my head to understand it. so your answer ether needs to be more simplistic or I need to find a place that explains the process extremely well.

Comment: @spydragon I said already. I am ready to explain. Which step you think is not clear?

Comment: how did you get the first equation using k and m.

Comment: @spydragon We want to choose $k$ and $m$ for which it would be true. And I make it!

Comment: ok that's how you got the values k and m, but what forced you, or inspired you to use two new variables and put them in the original equation the way that you have. in other words, I don't see how you got from this: $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ to this: $F_n+kF_{n-1}=m(F_{n-1}+kF_{n-2})$

Comment: I assumed that they are the same and I found values $k$ and $m$.

Comment: it was a shot in the dark?

Comment: No! I wanted to get a geometric progression (for which we need to get values of $k$ and $m$) and I got it!

Comment: I'm asking why use new variables in the first place to me, the equation you have is a very big jump from the original Fibonacci recurrence equation. I feel like you left out the steps to get there. or am I just missing some education that would explain why.

Comment: @spydragon Because the original recurrence seems easier, but does not give possibility to get a formula for $F_n$. By the way, if we get a geometric progression, we can get a formula for $F_n+kF_{n-1}.$ I think your problem is that you did not work with geometric progressions. If $a_{n+1}=a_nq,$ where $a_1\neq0$ and $q\neq0$ so $a_n=a_1q^{n-1}.$

Comment: ok now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your original equation is equivalent to (for integers k):

$$f_{2k} =  f_{k} + f_{k-1} $$
$$f_{2k-1} = f_{k}$$
Or, using matricies:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{2k}\\
    f_{2k-1}\\
    \end{pmatrix} 
=
A
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{k}\\
    f_{k-1}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
,\qquad
A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
By recursively applying this to an integer of the form $2k=2^r$:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{2^r}\\
    f_{(2^r-1)}\\
    \end{pmatrix} 
=
A^r
    \begin{pmatrix}
    f_{1}\\
    f_{0}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
,\qquad
A^r=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    {F}_{r+1} & {F}_{r}\\
    {F}_{r} & {F}_{r-1}\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
where ${F}_{r}$ is the rth Fibonacci number, ${F}_{0} = 0$

resolving components and using initial conditions:
$$
f_{2^r} = {F}_{r+1} + {F}_{r} = {F}_{r+2}
$$
similairly,
$$
f_{(2^r-1)} = {F}_{r+1}
$$
I couldn't take it any further than this for other values of k... I got the idea to use matrices from this German guy on YouTube (link is him doing a similar method but with the Fibonacci sequence itself): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WT_TGxQrV1k

Comment: sorry, this is incorrect. only because of a mistake that I made $f_2$ is actually supposed to be $f_0+f_1$ which equals $2$

Comment: edited that part out :)

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: your second equation $f_{2k-1}=f_k$ should be $f_{2k+1}=f_k$, sorry I didn't notice this earlier. try to generate this sequence with you'r equations to check it: $1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3,...$ with the first two terms being $f_0$ and $f_1$

Comment: may I ask, how did the Fibonacci numbers appear? and shouldn't $F_{r+1}$ be $F_{r+2}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I only meant to show you an approach to solve the problem, you could definitely adapt it to work with these changes to the question. You can find the general form for a matrix to the power of an integer by using matrix diagonalisation (Note that the eigenvalues of the matrix are the golden ratio). You can check the general form of the matrix to this power by using proof by induction (To be honest I guessed it, and checked it with this method).

Comment: ok, but since I have only recently learned about matrices recently I will have to learn a bit more before I can do anything with this. thanks anyway